# Summernote wraps <p><br></p> for insertNode()

Tags: javascript, summernote

I am trying to insert a simple `img` tag into the editor.

```js
jQuery('<img />').attr('src', '/uploads/images/' + res.data.filename);
jQuery('.summernote').summernote('insertNode', $image[0]);
```

I expect to see

```
<img src="/uploads/images/image.jpg" />
```

What I am getting is

```
<p><br><img src="/uploads/images/image.jpg" /></p>
```

I even append the image object into a paragraph object but then I get `<p><br></p>` before and after the node.

Not seeing this behavior obviously written in the plugin source file.

Has anyone applied custom functions to just insert in the plain node?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use 'insertImage' function instead of 'insertNode'.
Here is the docs:
[insertImage](http://summernote.org/jsduck/#!/api/editing.Editor-method-insertImage)

Comment: I was using `insertImage()` originally. I understand why it is doing this now however.

Answer (score 0):

Understand why it adds the wrapper when I am inserting a node on a new line. It's there as soon as I add a new line that it creates the wrapper aleready.

Answer (score 0):

Make a tweak in the summernote plugin.
You can change "blankspace" in summernote.js in line 873 I think

```
blankHTML = env.isMSIE && env.browserVersion < 11 ? '&nbsp;' : '<br>';
```

to, for example

```
blankHTML = '';
```

A better option would be to add your blankHTML tag also to summernote.
(Just start to go to the emptyPara tag in summernote.js. Summernote API is well made and easy to understand. But I'm not sure you can change blankHTML before initializing summernote.)
Bravo for their job and all the people who contribute with plugins in github.